# Is it possible to view Mapillary photos on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, mapillary

Mapillary ([link](https://www.mapillary.com)) provide streetview-like photos of many areas. There is a plugin available for the Openstreetmap editor 'JOSM' which provides an interface to view the photos (which is sometimes more helpful than the Mapillary website's interface).

Is there any way to duplicate this on QGIS - to view Mapillary photos using QGIS?

Comment: I cannot give you a definite answer, but there is already an implementation of Mapillary services in ArcGIS, so try an internet search for "Mapillary ArcGIS" to get some results for reading in detail ... maybe in that way an implementation of Mapillary should be possible for QGIS ... you can also ask for that feature in the own mapillary forum at http://forum.mapillary.com/

Comment: Not beautiful, but could work: According to Mapillary you can retrieve a JSON of any picture sequence containing the coordinates and file keys. You could create vertices out of these coordinates and parse the link to the photo using the keys. You can then open the photo in any location using an action. I've tried to use MapTips on these links but that doesn't work well. Maybe it's possible for you to store a sequence of photo's locally?

Comment: Thanks both. @Hydrographer that sounds promising but a bit of work... (not least to understand the Mapillary API from scratch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapillary support recently provided me with the following explanation, all credits to them.

Paste in your browser: `https://a.mapillary.com/v2/s/<-sequence_key->?client_id=<-client_id->`

With:

- `<-sequence_key->`: key of image sequence. You can copy it from the 'Advanced Options' in Mapillary.
- `<-client_id->`: Account settings > Developers > Register application (generates a key)

The return is a JSON that can be [converted to csv](https://json-csv.com/). It will contain coordinates and the image keys. Generate points in QGIS (Delimited Text or CSV Import).

Parse the keys in the following URL in the attribute table:

`https://d1cuyjsrcm0gby.cloudfront.net/<img_key>/thumb-320.jpg`

The large picture is stored at `*/thumb-2048`

The final link can be used to open the image in an 'Action' or a HTML MapTip. It would be best to remove the `https:` part of the string.

You could also let QGIS Actions open the photo on the map in Mapillary:

`https://www.mapillary.com/app/user/<-username->?lat=<-parse_lat_here->&lng=<-parse_lon_here->&z=17&pKey=<-parse_key_here->`

In terms of time consumption Mapillary advises Python or JS. Will work in FME as well. Hope it helps you forward.

Comment: Thank you - and thanks to Mapillary too. I've not tested this yet but it seems like a sound answer given what I already know so I've marked the answer as accepted. Will report back after a trial.

Comment: See more details here http://blog.mapillary.com/product/2017/04/12/how-to-retrieve-mapillary-images-to-use-in-external-tools.html

Answer (score 3):

Mapillary photos possible view in QGIS via plugin https://github.com/geodrinx/mapillary (not available in official QGIS plugin repository). For install it need download this plugin from GitHub and put 'mapillary' folder in QGIS plugin folder (for example C:\Users\USER_NAME.qgis2\python\plugins). Plugin allow download Mapillary photo location in current QGIS map view anв display photos in browser by click on point using 'Feature action' tool in Attribute panel

[image]

Comment: this plugin does not work with QGIS 3

Answer (score 2):

go2mapillary (https://github.com/enricofer/go2mapillary) - tool for browsing Mapillary images with QGIS3

YouTube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mup1rctNVsA

[image]

Comment: gotomapillary crash with QGIS3 (see issue https://github.com/enricofer/go2mapillary/issues/41 )